# Difference between E( expression ) and E[ expression ] for expected value

Tags: probability, statistics

I don't understand the difference in notation between E( expression ) and E[ expression ] for [expected value][1]. The Wikipedia article seems to indicate E( ) is used for an arbitrary function of X, but I'm not sure what the difference in meaning is.

Google pointed me to an example of a usage difference [here][2], but the article didn't help to resolve my misunderstanding much:

> In the following the operations E[ ] and Var[ ] (square brackets as
>   opposed to parentheses before !) mean expected value and variance with
>   respect to the structure function (prior distribution) U(η, θ) over
>   HxΘ.

Also, what does it mean when expected value is applied as an operator?.

Comment: References [1] and [2] are missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would never mind about it. I personally use $E[X]$ as $X$ is a random variable. For its samples $x$ then I use the density for example $f_X(x)$, here ().

Expected value can also be though as the most likely sample (on average, where the average is taken with respect to the probability density function) from a stochastic process. For example if you have a standard normal Gaussian distributed $X\sim {\cal{N}}(\mu=0,\sigma=1)$ then you might expect that a given $x$ should be (most of the time) around $0$.

As an operator $E[X]$ is linear; such as $$E[a_1X+b_1Y]=a_1E[X]+b_1E[Y]$$. The name operator indicates that you apply it to some random variable or a group of them in a linear way.

Comment: The wording "normal Gaussian" uses two words that are generally taken to have the same meaning: a normal random variable is a Gaussian random variable is a normal random variable. The follow-up ".. you might expect that a given $x$ should be around $0$" is false for normal random variables in general: only for normal random variables with means near $0$ and **small variance** should we expect the value to be near $0$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate yes I meant "normal" as zero mean and variance $1$. I forgot the word *standard*. I edit now. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: *Expected value can also be though as the most likely sample*... Not. At. All.

Comment: @did Ok I think I should add on average.

Comment: To be sure you got the point, let me add an example: if X is Bernoulli, the event [X=E(X)] has probability zero, in fact, the event [E(X)-u<X<E(X)+u] also has probability zero, for some positive u, hence X is **never** around E(X).

Comment: @Did thank you. I got the point.